# Spring Cloud Sleuth with custom retryer or custom builder

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, feign, spring-cloud-sleuth

`TraceFeignClientAutoConfiguration` overrides default Feign builder with this:

```
static Feign.Builder builder(BeanFactory beanFactory) {
    return Feign.builder().retryer(Retryer.NEVER_RETRY).client(client(beanFactory));
}
```

Why is retryer set to `NEVER_RETRY`? Can I use a custom retryer with Sleuth? Can I use a custom builder (i.e. `io.github.resilience4j.feign.Resilience4jFeign.Builder`) with Sleuth?